# Claim based Authorization (Skipping the subject argument)

Tags: casl

In the docs it shows that you can skip the subject and specify just the action but each time I do that, I get an error asking for subject. How can I implement claim based authorization without supplying the subject?

```
import { Ability } from '@casl/ability';

export default new Ability([
  {
    action: 'read',
  }
]);
```

> Property 'subject' is missing in type '{ action: string; }' but
> required in type 'SubjectRawRule<string, ExtractSubjectType,
> MongoQuery>'.ts(2741)

[In the docs](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/define-rules#the-shape-of-raw-rule), it shows the rawRule interface showing subject as an optional parameter:

```
  interface RawRule {
  action: string | string[]
  subject?: string | string[]
  /** an array of fields to which user has (or not) access */
  fields?: string[]
  /** an object of conditions which restricts the rule scope */
  conditions?: any
  /** indicates whether rule allows or forbids something */
  inverted?: boolean
  /** message which explains why rule is forbidden */
  reason?: string
}
```

Comment: is https://github.com/stalniy/casl/issues/305 the issue?

Comment: No, it's this issue here: https://github.com/stalniy/casl/issues/525
However the solution is using defineAbility, PureAbility and I'd like to use the JSON method to define rules